# angular Component no reload

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

angular Component no reload

```
{
  path: 'content/:nodeId/:key',
  component: ContentComponent
}
```

url:

- content/1/1
- content/2/1
- content/3/1

**`ContentComponent`** is singleton mode?

Comment: can't understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 5 routing to same component but different param, not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738911/angular-5-routing-to-same-component-but-different-param-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The component will not reload if you navigate to it with the router or an anchor tag that users a routerLink. It will reload it you type the url in the browser address bar.

Comment: my component still reloads:

Answer (score 0):

Components will not reload - it's kind of single page application where Angular helps you to route to different components without loading - this happens when you use `routerLink` or `router.navigate()` methods

Instead of `routerLink` use `href` on your html with the route name the page will reload for you - hope this helps - happy coding :)