# Routing to same component with different routing is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular project in which I have a navbar to route to different components. Two of the navigations in the navbar navigate to the same component but with different parameters. When I try to navigate to any of these two navigations from navbar it works fine.

But if I try to navigate from one of these navigations to other navigation with the same route and different parameter, it is not working.

My ngOnit function

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.configId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
        this.getConfigurations();
    }
```

Looking at an answer from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738911/angular-5-routing-to-same-component-but-different-param-not-working) I changed my code to

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.configId = params['id']
        })
        this.getConfigurations();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void{
        this.sub.unsubscribe()
    }
```

But still I see the same behaviour.

### Edit

Route configuration

```
{ path: 'admin/program/:id', component: ConfigurationView , canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {
        breadcrumb: [
            {
              label: 'Admin',
              url: ''
            },
            {
                label: 'Program ',
                url: ''
            }
          ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you post your routes configuration into your question please?

Comment: @RazRonen added route configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is only called when a component is inserted to the DOM Tree.

When you navigate in the same path with just different id, Angular doesn't re-render the component.(so `ngOnInit` is not called again and you cannot get `id` inside the `ngOnInit`)

Instead, you should watch your params change like what you did, but you need to move your `getConfiguration()` inside the subscription callback.

```js
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.configId = params['id']
  this.getConfigurations();
})
```